# Can I connect two iPhone by using the iBeacon technology?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, proximity

I really haven't read into much about iBeacons beyond the fact that they are low energy bluetooth transmitters that are able to detect nearby proximity devices. I am aware that there are beacon devices such as estimote that allows users to get prompts when entering their proximity. However, I am wondering if two iPhones can act as both beacons and receivers at the same time. So is possible for User A to be able to connect to User B when he arrives in a particular distance of the person?

By connect what I mean is for some sort of interaction to occur.

(e.g. Notifying User A that User B is nearby or exchanging messages that these users would like to send to people that comes in their proximity)

Thanks guys.

Comment: GameKit provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **iPhones can both act as iBeacons and receive iBeacon signals.**  But they can only act as an iBeacon when the transmitting app is in the foreground.

What you suggest is all possible, but it is important to note that **the iBeacon concept is connectionless**.  It is a one way transmission of a simple identifier from beacon to receiver.  If you want to make a connection and exchange data, you need a separate mechanism like the internet or a non-iBeacon Bluetooth connection.

Comment: To clarify when you mean a one way transmission of a simple identifier, do you mean that the function of the iBeacons is solely to identify the incoming transmission and if i were to add functionalities, I would have to do so through other means?

Comment: An iBeacon is a transmit only device.  It constantly transmits a 20 byte unique identifier.  It's function is for receiving devices, typically mobile phones, to know they are in proximity to that unique beacon.  Any additional functionality must be layered in by adding additional software or hardware to this very simple system.